# Draw google chart without waiting for all the images in the page to be loaded

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google charts with this code in the `<head>` of my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  ...
</script>
```

However, this way `drawChart` is not called until the document **and all of its contents including images** is fully loaded. That is way too extreme.

Is there a way to have it wait only for the html page to be loaded and the dom to be ready, but not for all the images and stuff to be completely loaded?

Comment: The reason the loader waits for the document to finish loading is to make the chart rendering more reliable.  The document elements must be rendered in order to create a chart references them, in particular.  It might be feasible to add a setting for controlling what to wait for.  Without that, do what @WhiteHat suggests and defer loading other things like images until after the chart loader is satisfied.